# Why is the suggested practice in dotnet core to use environment variables for application secrets?

Tags: security, .net-core

I understand that storing secrets in configuration files has tendency to end up accidentally committed to a source repository and this is the suggested practice to avoid that, however environment variables do not seem secure to me.

If an application is using system wide environment variables every process and user instantly has access, so this just should not be used ever.

If an application is using user environment variables then every process spawned from the account or application has a copy of these variables. So secrets are not isolated to the scope of the application.

Considering these user variables are stored in the registry, why use these over a file with the correct ACL's?
So can someone tell me why this is considered a secure option? 
Am I missing something here?